# Docker : SqlException: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api

I have created a asp.net core webapi and trying to run it within docker for windows. I am getting error SqlException: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. It seems like my api is not connecting to Sql Server when called via docker url. I am able to otherwise access it via IISExpress.

I also tried creating user in SSMS but doesn't seem to have resolved the issue

This is how my connection string looks like

```
 "ConnectionStrings": { "ProductDB": "Data Source=xxxx;Database=ProductsDB;Integrated Security=true;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False;" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to connect to the SqlServer instance from sql server studio or use a command line tool to check the connection to sql server. Also, can you try to connect using user name and password rather than Integrated Security = false

Answer (score -1):

You need to set

```
integrated security=false
```

[Integrated Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlConnection_ConnectionString)